# certificate verify failed google api

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, google-calendar-api

I am Using google calendar api, on python 3.6. Any API call I make fails because of certification verify failure. My Service Account is fine and valid. I initiate an instance of the class and then call `get_calendar_list` method.

The code is:

```
from .auth_service import get_credentials
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
import json


class CalendarService:
    def __init__(self, calendar_id=''):
        self.credentials = get_credentials()
        self.authed_session = AuthorizedSession(self.credentials)
        self.service_base_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList'
        self.calendar_id = calendar_id

    def get_service_url(self):
        return('{base_url}/{calendar_id}'.format(
            base_url=self.service_base_url,
            calendar_id=self.calendar_id))

    def get_calendar(self):
        response = self.authed_session.get(self.get_service_url())
        calendar = response.json()
        return calendar

    def get_calendar_list(self):
        response = self.authed_session.get(self.service_base_url)
        calendar_list = response.json()
        return calendar_list
```

Output of pip freeze

```
aniso8601==3.0.0
cachetools==2.1.0
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.4
Flask-HTTPAuth==3.2.3
Flask-RESTful==0.3.6
google-auth==1.4.1
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
pytz==2018.4
requests==2.18.4
rsa==3.4.2
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

The error is:

```
C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\Scripts\python.exe C:/Workspace/Techroom/lazyhour-server/main.py
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 279-826-945
 * Running on http://localhost:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
C:\Workspace\Techroom\lazyhour-server\util\service_account.json
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2018 15:22:56] "GET /calendar/list HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 88, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 595, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\flask_httpauth.py", line 93, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\lazyhour-server\main.py", line 45, in get
    return calendar_service.get_calendar_list()
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\lazyhour-server\util\calendar_service.py", line 25, in get_calendar_list
    response = self.authed_session.get(self.service_base_url)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 198, in request
    self._auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\google\auth\credentials.py", line 121, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\service_account.py", line 322, in refresh
    request, self._token_uri, assertion)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 145, in jwt_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 106, in _token_endpoint_request
    method='POST', url=token_uri, headers=headers, body=body)
  File "C:\Workspace\Techroom\venvs\lazyhour\lazyhour\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 124, in __call__
    six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
    # Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)'),))
```

Comment: Have your performed [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth)?

Answer (score 0):

First off would you mind trying this with a current copy of cryptography installed? We’ll then want to verify what kind of Authorization header is being passed to Requests by google’s auth methods.

As an aside, are you using a machine that may have a custom cert bundle (i.e. a corporate or third-party managed machine)? Or are you behind any sort of firewall that may be doing traffic analysis?